# How can I make a native app that will pick and design charts according to the name fetched from API?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want my `TabDashboardDetails.js` to find out which chart to be displayed according to the name of the chart fetched from API. In `TabDashboardDetails.js` I want to replace `CogniAreaChart` with a component that will have specific view for fetched chart and can also take data from API.

Here is my TabDashboardDetails.js

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultScrollView from '../components/default/DefaultScrollView';
import ChartView from '../components/default/ChartView';
import CogniAreaChart from '../components/CogniAreaChart';
import { mapNameToChart } from '../utils/commonFunctions';
import { areaChartData } from '../chartData';

const TabDashboardDetail = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const tabsConfig = route.params.tabsConfig;
  const ChartToDispay = mapNameToChart();
  return (
    <DefaultScrollView>
      {tabsConfig.components.map((comp) => {
        console.log(tabsConfig.components);
        return (
          <ChartView key={comp.name} title={comp.name}>
            <CogniAreaChart
              name={comp.name}
              areaChartData={areaChartData}
              height={200}
            />
          </ChartView>
        );
      })}
    </DefaultScrollView>
  );
};


export default TabDashboardDetail;
```

I want to pick charts from `commonfunctions.js` that I have used:

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {
  AreaChart,
  BarChart,
  LineChart,
  PieChart,
  SingleCircularProgress,
  Histogram,
  SimpleTable,
  BubbleChart,
  CandlestickChart,
  SankeyChart,
  ScatterPlot,
  StackedBarChart,
  WaterfallChart,
  TreeMap,
  MixAndMatch,
  SimpleCard,
  BlogTable,
  LiquidTable,
} from 'react-native-svg-charts';

export const mapNameToChart = (name) => {
  const nameToChart = {
    AreaChart: AreaChart,
    BarGraph: BarChart,
    LineChart: LineChart,
    PieChart: PieChart,
    SingleCircularProgress: SingleCircularProgress,
    Histogram: Histogram,
    SimpleTable: SimpleTable,
    BubbleChart: BubbleChart,
    CandlestickChart: CandlestickChart,
    SankeyChart: SankeyChart,
    ScatterPlot: ScatterPlot,
    StackedBarGraph: StackedBarChart,
    WaterfallTable: WaterfallChart,
    TreeMap: TreeMap,
    MixAndMatch: MixAndMatch,
    SimpleCard: SimpleCard,
    BlogCard: BlogTable,
    LiquidGauge: LiquidTable,
  };

  return nameToChart[name];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to import all the chart types in the file containing `mapNameToChart` and map the name to the Chart type accordingly. Then You can try this

```
const ChartToDispay = mapNameToChart(name);

<ChartToDisplay {...your_props_here} />
```

Comment: what should be my next steps?

Comment: updated the question, I am not able to get title={comp.name}, while on console.log(tabsconfog.components); its showing data correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: solved title problem by returning proper props. Now how can I display charts based on their names fetched from array and using commonfunctions.js

Answer (score 0):

In your `mapNameToChart` function it looks like `AreaChart` is an actual component and the rest are just `string` names of components instead of the components themselves.  You want to change it so that all of the entries in the map are the components.  You want `mapNameToChart(name)` to return a callable component.  Then you can call that component with your props.

I'm not fully understanding your the API comes into play here, but it seems like we get the props by looking up the name?  I don't know the the API data comes from, so I'm expecting the `components` array to be passed as a prop to the `CustomChart`.

```
const CustomChart = ({name, components, ...props}) => {
  // get the component function/class from your map
  const Component = mapNameToChart(chart);
  // find the component configuration from your API
  const config = components.find(obj => obj.name === name);
  // call with props from the config and passed down props
  return (
    <Component
      {...config}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: updated the question, I am not able to get title={comp.name}, while on console.log(tabsconfog.components); its showing data correctly. What am I doing wrong?